# Pool with permanent objects for each worker without “global” keyword

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using a Pool to benefit of multiple cores. Each worker in the pool needs its own Calculator object. The initialization of calculator is quite time consuming, so I would like to have it generated only once per worker in the pool and not every time, a new task arrives. The only way, I got this working was by using the “ugly“ keyword `global`. Is there a “cleaner” way to implement this?

I would like to avoid queues (parent thread is often sigkill’d and leaves child processes when using queues) and managers (performance too slow).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import multiprocessing

def init_pool():
    global calculator
    calculator = Calculator()   # should only executed ones per worker

def run_pool(args):
    return calculator.calculate(*args)  # time consuming calculation

class Organiser():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init_pool)

    def process(self, tasks):
        results = self.__pool.map(run_pool, tasks)
        return results
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a way to achieve what you want (initialize exactly once per worker).

But the following seems to work if you want to initialize "Calculator" exactly once for the whole **group** of workers.

```
def run_pool(args):
    calculator,arg = args
    return calculator.calculate(arg)  # time consuming calculation

class Organiser():
    def __init__(self):
        self.calculator = Calculator()
        self.__pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)

    def process(self, tasks):
        results = self.__pool.map(run_pool, [(self.calculator,data) for data in tasks])
        return results
```

To initialize exactly once per worker, it appears to me that you must use global variables or singletons (equivalent). I will await other answers to your question as well :)

Regards,
Siddharth